# how to find size of android repository

Tags: android, git

I am following the below steps to download repo for building an android marshmellow image .

```
 cd ~
$ mkdir myandroid
$ mkdir bin
$ cd myandroid
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
$ ~/bin/repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6.0.1_r22
$ ~/bin/repo sync
```

after last step it has already download 18 GB and still going on

is there anyway to find the size of this repo before downloading it.

I have searched the following link

[See the size of a github repo before cloning it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/see-the-size-of-a-github-repo-before-cloning-it)

but above method gives output of message : unknown file

how to find it ?

Comment: Check this answer it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28679647/3059033